Why is my search function really slow on folders with a lot of files?
I am trying to search files using this logic inside a Region (Which is a folder) and display them. The problem is on when there's a lot of files (for example like 200k) it takes like 10 minutes to search, in folders with not a lot of files its really quick. What could be the best way to speed up the search? I tried using runspaces too but no success, the time to search didn't change at all.
I am using Powershell version 5.1.22621.4249
function Convert-FileName { 
    param (
        [string]$fileName
    )

    $fileName = $fileName.TrimStart('.')

    if ($fileName -match "^(\d+)\.([A-Z]+)\.01\.(\d+)\.(\d{8})$") {
        return @{
            "PayerID"    = $matches[1]
            "Region"     = $matches[2]
            "CheckNum"   = $matches[3]
            "CheckDate"  = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[4], "yyyyMMdd", $null)
        }
    } else {
        return $null
    }
}

$buttonSearch.Add_Click({
    $region = $comboBoxRegion.Text
    $payIDRange = $textBoxPayID.Text
    $checkNumRange = $textBoxCheckNum.Text
    $checkDateRange = $textBoxCheckDate.Text

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($global:selectedFolder)) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please choose a folder before searching.")
        return
    }

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($region)) {
        $dataGridView.Rows.Clear()
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select a region.")
        return
    }

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($payIDRange) -or $payIDRange -notmatch "^\d+-\d+$") {
        $dataGridView.Rows.Clear()
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Invalid Pay ID range.")
        return
    }

    $global:totalResults = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]

    $payIDStart, $payIDEnd = $payIDRange -split "-", 2
    $payIDStart = [int]$payIDStart
    $payIDEnd = [int]$payIDEnd

    $allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "$global:selectedFolder\$region" -File 

    foreach ($file in $allFiles) {
        $fileInfo = Convert-FileName -fileName $file.Name
        if ($fileInfo -ne $null) {
            $extractedPayerID = [int]$fileInfo.PayerID
            $payIDValid = $extractedPayerID -ge $payIDStart -and $extractedPayerID -le $payIDEnd

            $checkNumValid = $true
            if ($checkNumRange -ne "") {
                $checkNumStart, $checkNumEnd = $checkNumRange -split "-", 2
                $checkNumValid = $fileInfo.CheckNum -ge [int]$checkNumStart -and $fileInfo.CheckNum -le [int]$checkNumEnd
            }

            $checkDateValid = $true
            if ($checkDateRange -ne "") {
                $startDate, $endDate = $checkDateRange -split " - ", 2
                $startDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($startDate.Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd", $null)
                $endDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($endDate.Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd", $null)
                $checkDateValid = $fileInfo.CheckDate -ge $startDate -and $fileInfo.CheckDate -le $endDate
            }

            if ($payIDValid -and $checkNumValid -and $checkDateValid) {
                $resultObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                    Name = $file.Name
                    Path = $file.FullName
                }
                $global:totalResults.Add($resultObject)
            }
        }
    }

    if ($global:totalResults.Count -eq 0) {
        $dataGridView.Rows.Clear()
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("No results found.")
        return
    }

    $global:currentPage = 0
    Show-Results
})

I tried adding runspaces to perform quicker search, but it didn't succeed.
function Search-Files {
    Param(
        [string]$selectedFolder,
        [string]$region,
        [string]$payIDRange,
        [string]$checkNumRange,
        [string]$checkDateRange
    )

    $payIDStart, $payIDEnd = $payIDRange -split "-"
    $payIDStart = [int]$payIDStart
    $payIDEnd = [int]$payIDEnd

    $allFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path "$selectedFolder\$region" -File

    $file_count = $allFiles.Count
    $cpu_count = [Environment]::ProcessorCount
    $optimal_runspaces = [Math]::Min($cpu_count, $file_count)
    $file_chunks = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object[]]]::new($optimal_runspaces)

    $runspace_pool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $optimal_runspaces)
    $runspace_pool.Open()

    $chunk_size = [Math]::Ceiling($file_count / $optimal_runspaces)
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $optimal_runspaces; $i++) {
        $start = $i * $chunk_size
        $end = [Math]::Min(($start + $chunk_size - 1), ($file_count - 1))

        $file_chunks.Add($allFiles[$start..$end])
    }

    $scriptblock = {
        Param($files, $payIDStart, $payIDEnd, $checkNumRange, $checkDateRange)
        function Convert-FileName { 
            param (
                [string]$fileName
            )
        
            $fileName = $fileName.TrimStart('.')
        
            if ($fileName -match "^(\d+)\.([A-Z]+)\.01\.(\d+)\.(\d{8})$") {
                return @{
                    "PayerID"    = $matches[1]
                    "Region"     = $matches[2]
                    "CheckNum"   = $matches[3]
                    "CheckDate"  = [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[4], "yyyyMMdd", $null)
                }
            } else {
                return $null
            }
        }

        $results = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
        foreach ($file in $files) {
            $fileInfo = Convert-FileName $file.Name
            if ($fileInfo -eq $null) { continue }

            $extractedPayerID = [int]$fileInfo.PayerID.Trim()
            if ($extractedPayerID -lt $payIDStart -or $extractedPayerID -gt $payIDEnd) { continue }

            $checkNumValid = $true
            if ($checkNumRange -ne "") {
                $checkNumStart, $checkNumEnd = $checkNumRange -split "-"
                $checkNumValid = ($fileInfo.CheckNum -ge [int]$checkNumStart -and $fileInfo.CheckNum -le [int]$checkNumEnd)
            }

            $checkDateValid = $true
            if ($checkDateRange -ne "") {
                $startDate, $endDate = $checkDateRange -split " - "
                $startDate = [datetime]::Parse($startDate)
                $endDate = [datetime]::Parse($endDate)
                $checkDateValid = ($fileInfo.CheckDate -ge $startDate -and $fileInfo.CheckDate -le $endDate)
            }

            if ($checkNumValid -and $checkDateValid) {
                $results.Add($file)
            }
        }
        return $results
    }

    $runspaces = @{}
    foreach ($chunk in $file_chunks) {
        $runspace = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($scriptblock).AddArgument($chunk).AddArgument($payIDStart).AddArgument($payIDEnd).AddArgument($checkNumRange).AddArgument($checkDateRange)
        $runspace.RunspacePool = $runspace_pool
        $runspaces[$runspace] = $runspace.BeginInvoke()
    }

    while ($runspaces.Values | Where-Object { -not $_.IsCompleted }) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }

    $all_results = @()
    foreach ($runspace in $runspaces.Keys) {
        $all_results += $runspace.EndInvoke($runspaces[$runspace])
        $runspace.Dispose()
    }

    $runspace_pool.Close()
    $runspace_pool.Dispose()

    return $all_results
}

$buttonSearch.Add_Click({
    $region = $comboBoxRegion.Text
    $payIDRange = $textBoxPayID.Text
    $checkNumRange = $textBoxCheckNum.Text
    $checkDateRange = $textBoxCheckDate.Text

    if ($global:selectedFolder -eq "") {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please choose a folder before searching.")
        return
    }

    if ($region -eq "") {
        $dataGridView.Rows.Clear()
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select a region.")
        return
    }

    if ($payIDRange -eq "" -or $payIDRange -notmatch "^\d+-\d+$") {
        $dataGridView.Rows.Clear()
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Invalid Pay ID range.")
        return
    }

    $results = Search-Files -selectedFolder $global:selectedFolder -region $region -payIDRange $payIDRange -checkNumRange $checkNumRange -checkDateRange $checkDateRange

    if ($results.Count -eq 0) {
        $dataGridView.Rows.Clear()
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("No results found.")
        return
    }

    $global:totalResults = $results

    $global:currentPage = 0
    Show-Results
})

Code with Cache Function Implemented:
$global:Cache = @{}
$buttonSearch.Add_Click({
    $region = $comboBoxRegion.Text
    $payIDRange = $textBoxPayID.Text
    $checkNumRange = $textBoxCheckNum.Text
    $checkDateRange = $textBoxCheckDate.Text

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($global:selectedFolder)) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please choose a folder before searching.")
        return
    }

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($region)) {
        $dataGridView.Rows.Clear()
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Please select a region.")
        return
    }

    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($payIDRange) -or $payIDRange -notmatch "^\d+-\d+$") {
        $dataGridView.Rows.Clear()
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Invalid Pay ID range.")
        return
    }

    $global:totalResults = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[object]

    $payIDStart, $payIDEnd = $payIDRange -split "-", 2
    $payIDStart = [int]$payIDStart
    $payIDEnd = [int]$payIDEnd

    $Directory = $global:selectedFolder + '\' + $region
    $allFiles = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($Directory, '*', [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)
    $startDate = $null
    $endDate = $null
    
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($checkDateRange)) {
        $dateParts = $checkDateRange -split " - ", 2
        if ($dateParts.Length -eq 2) {
            try {
                $startDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateParts[0].Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd", $null)
                $endDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($dateParts[1].Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd", $null)
            } catch {
                Write-Host "Error parsing dates: '$($dateParts[0].Trim())' or '$($dateParts[1].Trim())'. Please ensure they are in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format."
                return
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($filePath in $allFiles) {
        $file = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo $filePath
        $currentCacheKey = Generate-CacheKey -fileName $file.FullName -payIDRange $payIDRange -checkNumRange $checkNumRange -checkDateRange $checkDateRange
        
        if (-not $global:Cache.ContainsKey($currentCacheKey)) {
            $fileInfo = Convert-FileName -fileName $file.Name
            if ($fileInfo -ne $null) {
                $extractedPayerID = [int]$fileInfo.PayerID
                $payIDValid = $extractedPayerID -ge $payIDStart -and $extractedPayerID -le $payIDEnd
    
                $checkNumValid = $true
                if ($checkNumRange -ne "") {
                    $checkNumStart, $checkNumEnd = $checkNumRange -split "-", 2
                    $checkNumValid = $fileInfo.CheckNum -ge [int]$checkNumStart -and $fileInfo.CheckNum -le [int]$checkNumEnd
                }
    
                $checkDateValid = $true
                if ($checkDateRange -ne "") {
                    $checkDateValid = $fileInfo.CheckDate -ge $startDate -and $fileInfo.CheckDate -le $endDate
                }
    
                if ($payIDValid -and $checkNumValid -and $checkDateValid) {
                    $resultObject = [PSCustomObject] @{
                        Name = $file.Name
                        Path = $file.FullName
                    }
                    $global:totalResults.Add($resultObject)
                    $global:Cache[$currentCacheKey] = $resultObject
                } else {
                    $global:Cache[$currentCacheKey] = $null
                }
            } else {
                $global:Cache[$currentCacheKey] = $null
            }
        } else {
            $resultObject = $global:Cache[$currentCacheKey]
            if ($resultObject) {
                $global:totalResults.Add($resultObject)
            }
        }
    }

    if ($global:totalResults.Count -eq 0) {
        $dataGridView.Rows.Clear()
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("No results found.")
        return
    }

    $global:currentPage = 0
    Show-Results
})


This is a windows issue and not PS.  The problems has existed with Microsoft OS since DOS.

So there is no way to make the search faster?

What Convert-FileName and what does it do? [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($Directory,'*') would get the file list MUCH faster than Get-ChildItem but only as a string array of their full paths so I don't know if it would work with that cmdlet

What type of drive do you have?  Mechanical Drives the heads have to move.

I am including Convert-Filename on the post so you can see.

Generally speaking, to improve performance you should minimize calculations in any loop.
There is some code that is inside your foreach() loop that doesn't need to be:
            $startDate, $endDate = $checkDateRange -split " - ", 2
            $startDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($startDate.Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd", $null)
            $endDate = [datetime]::ParseExact($endDate.Trim(), "yyyy-MM-dd", $null)

$startDate and $endDate never change per file.
Initialize them before your foreach loop.
The same is true of your second attempt, but quite a bit worse. Adding a tab for each matching file will probably cause your UI to consume excessive memory and processor time while becoming unwieldy to use. I don't see where runspaces is implemented or where it would help. You were on the right track with your first attempt: gather all the files and info you need, then present the data. Building UI during processing will be slow.
You might opt to put some Measure-Command blocks around code you expect to be long-running. Also review this article about Powershell performance of various variable types.
Rules of thumb when optimizing: try to make the code executed in a loop as small and quick as possible, and try to make the loop execute as few times as possible.

Sorry, i included the wrong code, i edited the post so runspaces are there now.

To build on the helpful answer from Rich Moss and comments in the question:
"So there is no way to make the search faster?"
Not at all, but let's start with a rhetorical question:

Why using PowerShell 5.1 -an 8 years old software engine- if you target for the best performance?

Tweaking
You might tweak your current design even further, some general leads are described in the document PowerShell scripting performance considerations, besides:

What is in Convert-FileName???
Aside from the fact that the contents of this function might have an affect on the performance of your iteration, the overhead of the function call might play a role as well, see this question: What is the best way to reuse static code
Avoid repeated calls to a function
Saying that, this doesn't just concern custom functions but also native PowerShell cmdlets as the legacy New-Object cmdlet. Using the [PSCustomObject]@{ ... } type initiator is a lot faster:

Measure-Command {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 1e6; $i++) {
        $resultObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = 'Name'
            Path = 'FullName'
        }
    }
}

Measure-Command {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt 1e6; $i++) {
        $resultObject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            Name = 'Name'
            Path = 'FullName'
        }
    }
}




Syntax
Windows PowerShell (5.1)
PowerShell 7.4.5 (Core)




New-Object
90 secondes
39 secondes


[PSCustomObject]
8 secondes
5 secondes



Smarter
Aside from tweaking the iterations, you might rethink your whole design (or even the process behind it), 200k files in a folder is a lot to handle (even for the Explorer interface).

Get-ChildItem
The command Get-ChildItem -Path "$global:selectedFolder\$region" -File is probably expensive in your script, so simply try to avoid reloading this list if it isn't required by checking the folder's LastWriteTime knowing that you only retrieve the direct decedents in the folder and the folder's LastWriteTime will change if a file is added, removed or renamed.
Caching
The .Net version that comes with PowerShell 7 includes has an easy independent MemoryCache class that could be used for Get-ChildItem or to cache the result of all the casting, string manipulation and condition checking you do. You might also create a custom cache using a hash table that will look something like this:

$Global:Cache = @{}

foreach ($file in $allFiles) {
    if (-not $Cache.Contains($file.FullName) {
        $Cache[$file.FullName] = $(
            # # you original processing code (even it might result in an AutomationNull)
            # $fileInfo = Convert-FileName -fileName $file.Name
            # if ($fileInfo -ne $null) {
            # ...
            # }
        )
    }
    $resultObject = $Cache[$file.FullName] # Might return a $Null
    if ($Null -ne $resultObject) { $global:totalResults.Add($resultObject) }
}


multithreading
And if you have a "Filename" cache setup, you might also consider to start already populating it in the background once your $global:selectedFolder is known or changed based on e.g. a TextBox.Change event.


I included Convert-FIleName on the code now also i created a custom-cache function. I am including the new code with custom-cache function on the post.

And? Any results or answers on the counter questions? Does it run faster when invoke a second time? What if you place the Convert-FIleName code directly inside the foreach? What if you use a type initiator rather than New-Object? What about the  measurements of the different approaches and parts as suggested by @RichMoss?
